# Stepping into template classes with GDB

Tags: c++, templates, gdb

I'm working on implementing a balanced tree in c++, but the requirement of the assignment is that I have to use template classes. I thought of doing it with ints first and then converting to templates, but the test code we are given use templates by default.

When I compile my code with g++ class.h test.cxx -Wall -g -O0 everything seems to work fine until I get into gdb where it won't step into the template implementation. My template implementation file is included at the end of the header file, and gdb will allow me to set break points within it, but it never actually steps into the function. I've been using gdb through emacs, but it didn't work directly in gdb either. I would expect that step switches over to the template file when GDB gets to a function that is implimented there, but instead it tell's me that the line it thinks it should go to doesn't really exist. Here is a typical session:

```
(gdb) break set.template:7
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400c46: file set.template, line 7.
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/students/jeffris/csci2270/btree/debug

Breakpoint 1, main () at debug.cxx:9
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 3, set (this=0x7fffffffe550) at set.template:7
Line number 7 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb) 
set()
Line number 8 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb)  
Line number 9 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb) 
Line number 10 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb) 
main () at debug.cxx:10
(gdb) 
main_savitch_11::set<int>::empty (this=0x7fffffffe550) at set.template:70
Line number 70 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb) 
empty
Line number 71 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb)  
Line number 72 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
(gdb)
```

I've seen several posts around the web of other people having similar trouble but the threads all died off without resolution. I've tried a several ways of compiling the code including in individual pieces and then linking it all together, but no dice. Everyone else in my class has the same problem but has contented themselves using cout statements to debug which is very slow going way to debug with 10 functions calling each other. Has anyone else experienced this and found a resolution?

Comment: what version of GDB do you use? And what version of GCC? Both programs have recently made progress on these points. (GCC 4.6, GDB 7.3)

Comment: Can't you just define the class solely in the header, rather than including a  secondary implementation file? If your teacher won't accept that, then do it, and just move the code back to the implementation file once it's been debugged

Comment: and breakpoint lines should be in C++ file. So you should use `b set.cc:10`

Comment: Perhaps passing `-fno-inline` should help you...

Comment: I'm running debian testing on my personal computer using GCC 4.6.2 and GDB 7.3. The school computers are a slightly older version of Ubuntu but there isn't any difference in the way GDB reacts. -fno-inline didn't fix the problem. I don't think putting the template into the header would help because GDB won't even step into the header file when the inline functions are called. The answer regarding the text format may be onto something, my professor gave us the skeletons for the file and has a windows machine...

Comment: Well, my problem is solved in a pretty unsatisfactory way, but it will have to do for now. I followed @jalf suggestion and put the whole of the template implementation in the header file and gdb stepped right in. The book we use says that the implementation of a template class should be separate from the header file but the c++ standard requires that it be included in the header file so the work around was to include the template file in the header file. It must have been g++ or stabs that had the problem generating line numbers because it doesn't expect .template files.

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks like gdb on the platform you're using to debug cannot find the end-of-line delimiters for your `set.template` file.  For instance, the debug symbols seem to point to a proper line-number:

```
(gdb) break set.template:7
Breakpoint 3 at 0x400c46: file set.template, line 7.
```

But then you're getting this error-message that

```
Line number 7 out of range; set.template has 1 lines.
```

So gdb sees your `set.template` file, but it's unable to properly parse it and see the end-of-line delimiters in order to actually tell what line number to look at.  This can happen for instance if you wrote a file in Linux, and then compiled it on Windows.  Linux/Unix need only a line-feed for a newline, where-as Windows requires a carriage-return + line-feed combination.  So open your set.template file in a text-editor on the platform you're debugging on, and make sure that your file is not a single-line.  There could be other reasons why gdb is choking on the lines of your file, but this inability to see the end-of-line in your actual code-file is basically the reason for your issues, and has nothing to-do with an inability to debug templates ... gdb can debug templates just fine.

Comment: The header and template files did have some DOS line endings in them. I'm not sure why they didn't appear in emacs, usually they show up with a goofy ^M character. I used the dos2unix utility to convert over to what I assume is a satisfactory format. Creating a check sum with md5sum of the file before and after running that utility showed that the file was changed, I assume by correcting the EOL and EOF characters. I updated every file used to compile my set test code but it didn't change the way gdb reacted. Your explanation sounds very reasonable though, so I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: You may want to look at your file in a hex editor where you can see every byte of the file.  At the end of each line you should see only a line-feed character for Unix/Linux line endings.

Comment: I used hexl-mode in emacs. The EOL in the file converted to unix/linux format is 0x0a, and in the dos format it is just 0x0d with out the line feed after which was odd. Those characters are both single in all cases except when there is a blank line in between. Still no luck with gdb. I ran the inverse operation unix2dos on old assignments and gdb was still able to run through them alright, even though the line endings had been changed to 0d 0a. I can see why gdb would have had trouble with the original files of my template set class because there was no linux line return at all.